# how to make a webview wait for token?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with a React Native webview and I think I know the issue.  The webview is running before the token value is populated with the token?  How can I make the webview wait for the token before rendering?

I know this is the reason cause if i run the auth api and get the token and paste it where 'token' is, the web view renders correctly.

Code:

```
const getSetData = async() =>{
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((result) => {
            token = result;
        });
    }


    return (
        <View styles={styles.container}>
            <NavigationEvents
                    onDidFocus = {()=> {
                        getSetData();
                    }}
            />
            
            <View style={{alignItems:'center', marginTop: 60}}>
                <SLSHeader style={{height: 65, width: '100%'}} navigation={props.navigation} title="RAPID RATES"/>
                <View style={{padding:10, top: 20, marginTop:40, marginBottom:10, width:'95%', height:'90%'}}>
                    <WebView
                        source={{uri: 'http://myurl.com', headers:{"Authorization":token} }}
                        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the token in a `useState`.

```js
const [token, setToken] = useState('');

const getSetData = async() =>{
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((result) => {
            setToken(result);
        });
    }

...

{token && <WebView
            source={{uri: 'http://myurl.com', headers:{"Authorization":token} }}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
          />}
```

When token will be set, the component will re-render and the webview will load with correct token.

Comment: crazy thing is, I did that via useState and the token comes back blank???

Answer (score 0):

The crazy thing is, ive tried this and token consoles out blank.

```
export default function GetHelp (props) {
    let [token, setToken] = useState("");

    const getSetData = async() =>{
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((result) => {
            setToken(token);
            //token = result;
        });
    }


    return (
        <View styles={styles.container}>
            <NavigationEvents
                    onDidFocus = {()=> {
                        getSetData();
                        console.log("Set Token: ", token);
                    }}
            />

            <View style={{alignItems:'center', marginTop: 60}}>
                <SLSHeader style={{height: 65, width: '100%'}} navigation={props.navigation} title="RAPID RATES"/>
                <View style={{padding:10, top: 20, marginTop:40, marginBottom:10, width:'95%', height:'90%'}}>
                    <WebView
                        source={{uri: 'http://myurl.com', headers:{"Authorization":token} }}
                        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );  
}
```

the console logs prints blank???

Comment: setToken(token); should be setToken(result);  same result though.  token is blank even though if i console result, it shows the token???